# Android: audioManager.communicationDevice returns TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE on Android 14, even when bluetooth headset is connected

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, android-audiomanager, android-14

I have encountered this behaviour on Android 14, Pixel 6a when playing some ringtone in my app.

When I am executing the following code,

```
audioManager.communicationDevice?.type == TYPE_BLUETOOTH_A2DP
```

It returns false. The `communicationDevice` returned in this case is `TYPE_BUILTIN_EARPIECE` even though my air pods are connected.

This works fine on Android 13 however and it returns true for the same use case.

Is this a known issue/change in behavior? Could someone explain why this happens? Thanks!